# Where to place NGINX host configuration file?

Tags: nginx, yii, php, winginx

I've used [WINGINX](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HL-gvgOnOBo) to install NGINX, PHP-FPM, MySQL, MongoDB, NodeJS and MemcacheD on my Windows machine.

In the [Yii Framework documentation](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/quickstart.apache-nginx-config) I've found the following host configuration code:

```
server {
    set $host_path "/www/mysite";
    access_log  /www/mysite/log/access.log  main;

    server_name  mysite;
    root   $host_path/htdocs;
    set $yii_bootstrap "index.php";

    charset utf-8;

    location / {
        index  index.html $yii_bootstrap;
        try_files $uri $uri/ $yii_bootstrap?$args;
    }

    location ~ ^/(protected|framework|themes/\w+/views) {
        deny  all;
    }

    #avoid processing of calls to unexisting static files by yii
    location ~ \.(js|css|png|jpg|gif|swf|ico|pdf|mov|fla|zip|rar)$ {
        try_files $uri =404;
    }

    # pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on 127.0.0.1:9000
    #
    location ~ \.php {
        fastcgi_split_path_info  ^(.+\.php)(.*)$;

        #let yii catch the calls to unexising PHP files
        set $fsn /$yii_bootstrap;
        if (-f $document_root$fastcgi_script_name){
            set $fsn $fastcgi_script_name;
        }

        fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fsn;

        #PATH_INFO and PATH_TRANSLATED can be omitted, but RFC 3875 specifies them for CGI
        fastcgi_param  PATH_INFO        $fastcgi_path_info;
        fastcgi_param  PATH_TRANSLATED  $document_root$fsn;
    }

    location ~ /\.ht {
        deny  all;
    }
}
```

Where do I need to store this code?

I've used the hosteditor to create: http://project.loc, and the file: `index.php` is displayed correctly (located at: /winginx/home/project.loc/pubic_html).

I tried placing the code several directoires:

- /winginx/conf
- /winginx/conf/vhosts
- /winginx/home/project.loc

..but non of it worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Wingix Documentation](http://winginx.com/docs/vhosts) explains how to do this:

> you should create in the winginx\conf\vhosts folder a separate config
>   file named to domain name plus .conf, e.g. mysite.local.conf.
>
> After the config is added or edited, you should restart Winginx,
>   double-click start-winginx.exe.
>
> If something goes wrong after these manipulates, please read
>   winginx\logs\error.log.